# How to set UICollectionViewCell height from cellForItemAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So, I want to set UICollectionViewCell height from the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` instead of from

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
```

How can I do it? So I want to give height and width to my cells in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, not in the `collectionViewLayout: sizeForItemAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 2):

You have to still use `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`, but you may declare a public variable on the top of your swift file:

```
var cellSize = CGSize()
```

and in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate write something like this before `return cell`:

```
cellSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100) // set your desired width and height
```

then:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return cellSize
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can provide them estimate height with UICollectionViewFLowLayout

```
 UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*) self.CollectionViewLayout.collectionViewLayout;
    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,yourheight);
```

but if all the cell needs to have different heights then you need to implement 
sizeForItemAtIndexPath method form UICollecionViewController.

```
>        (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
> sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
>      return CGSizeMake(width, height);
>     
>     }
```